# Get angle between two scalar inputs

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I'm trying to make a game and in m working on the movement system

I'm trying to make the character look the way they are moving

I have two numbers, the horizontal axis and vertical axis; both are between -1 and 1

What I need is the angle that the point (h, v) is at

I would prefer the math to be linear as I am using bolt which is a flow language

Comment: Does your programming language have the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function?

Comment: that would work but my horizontal and vertical are often 0

Comment: It's fine when one of them is zero. There is only a problem when both are zero, because then there is no angle.

Comment: yes hopefully this will work because i can check if both are zero

Comment: @JaapScherphuis put that into the answers so i can accept is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual function for this is called [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) in most programming languages. So
$$\theta=atan2(y,x)$$
should give the angle (usually in radians) between the ray going from the origin to the point $(x,y)$ and the positive x-axis.

The function works for any point except of course the origin $(0,0)$, because then the angle is undefined.